# Two generators of $F_2$ must be free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Suppose we are given $a, b \in F_2$, that happen to generate it. Then must they be free generators? That is, there is no non-trivial reduced word on $a^{\pm 1}, b^{\pm 1}$ defining the identity. Equivalently, $a, b$ satisfy the universal property defining $F_2$.

I tried attacking this the first way: suppose $u$ and $v$ are free generators, then if I take a word on $a$ and $b$ I can rewrite it in terms of $u$ and $v$. But how do I know that if I took a non-trivial reduced word on $a, b$ defining the identity, it does not become trivial after reduction with $u$ and $v$?

I also tried to use the universal property. Then we get that if $a$ and $b$ are not free, $F_2$ is isomorphic to one of its propert quotients. Maybe this is not the case for $F_2$ specifically, but it may be for other groups, so no contradiction in sight once again.

I know this is true because it is used in a class I am taking. To prove that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is not free, the professor just exhibited two generators and a non-trivial relation.

Comment: Can you give an example of non-free generators?

Comment: $a, b, a^{-1}$ are non-free generators. The claim is that you cannot have *two* non-free generators...

Comment: I assume these generators are non-free because $a^{-1}$ is evaluable from $a$. So if I remove $a^{-1}$ I still get generators. So is the set of free generators the same as the minimal set of generators? Then obviously $\mathbb{F}_2$ cannot have a minimal set of generators with only 1 element. Otherwise it would be $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @freakish: They are non-free because there is a nontrivial word in three letters that reduces to the identity when you plug in $a, b, a^{-1}$ for the three letters.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, then I'm asking what's the difference between "non-free" and "minimal"?

Comment: @freakish a set of generators $x_1, \dots , x_k \in G$ is free whenever the following holds: the unique epimorphism $F_k \to G$ mapping hte $i$-th generator of $F_k$ to $x_i$ is an isomorphism. A set of generators is minimal when no proper subset of it is a set of generators. It does not seem that the two things are equivalent.

Comment: @Crostul Well, they are. Free implies minimal obviously (otherwise the mapping would not be injective). And minimal implies free because free groups are hopfian.

Comment: @freakish They are not the same. For example, $\langle 2, 3\rangle$ is a minimal, but non-free, generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed any pair of comprime integers generate $\mathbb{Z}$ but each generate a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user1729 Indeed, you are right. However if the set of generators of $F_n$ has exactly $n$ elements then it has to be both free and minimal. That's where hopfian arguments comes into play.

Comment: @freakish Ahh, I did wonder where/why you were trying to use Hopfian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to the following:

> Is every surjective group homomorphism $F_2 \to F_2$ necessarily injective?

Groups with this property are called *Hopfian groups*: see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group) .

In particular, it is stated that $F_n$ is Hopfian for all $n$: [proof](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_free_implies_Hopfian).

Thus, the answer to your question is yes: every set of 2 generators of $F_2$ is free.

Comment: Wait, the linked proof shows that $F_n$ is residually finite, but how do we know that finitely generated residually finite groups are Hopfian?

Comment: @Vincent sorry, I pasted the wrong link. Thanks for having alerted me.

Comment: Just went through the proof, very clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Crostul, Ok. Still the question from my comment is interesting... But likely the answer can be found somewhere else on that same site?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447820/is-a-free-group-of-finite-rank-hopfian

Comment: It is not hard to show that a finitely generated residually finite group is Hopfian. See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_residually_finite_implies_Hopfian)

Comment: As you see, this is not specific to $n=2$. However there's a more specific fact for pairs: in a free group, any two elements freely generate a free group, unless they commute (which is easily checkable, and actually holds iff they have a common root).