# Is there an algorithm that, given a finite presentation of a free group, outputs a free basis for the group?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, computability, free-groups, group-presentation

I have been stuck on this problem for two weeks, and I'm not sure I believe it to be true anymore. I have no idea how to proceed. I know nothing about algorithms or how to find them, this is my first time trying a question of this sort and I am at the end of my wits. Can someone give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: With questions like this, you need to make it clear whether it is a theoretical question (does an algorithm exist) or whether are looking for a practical algorithm that you can run on a computer.

Comment: Seeing as how this is for a group theory class, I assume that this is more of a theoretical question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $G$ is a free group on $n$ generators (for some finite $n$).  Then a set $S\subseteq G$ is a free basis for $G$ iff $S$ generates $G$ and $|S|\leq n$ (see [Is a free group of finite rank Hopfian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447820/is-a-free-group-of-finite-rank-hopfian) for instance).  So, you can search through all possible $n$-tuples until you find one that generates.

More details are hidden below.

> First, you can compute the rank $n$ of the free group from its presentation by abelianizing and using linear algebra.  Now given any finite list $S$ of words in the generators, you can test whether $S$ generates the group by just trying all possible ways to string together elements of $S$ and their inverses and then reduce them using the relations, to see whether you eventually get all the generators in the presentation.  (This will eventually halt if $S$ does generate, but will run forever if $S$ does not generate.)  Now dovetail this test for all possible lists $S$ of $n$ words.  Since the group is free on $n$ generators, you must eventually find some $S$ that does generate, and therefore must be a free basis since it has at most $n$ elements.

Comment: Given a finite set $S \subset G$ of size $n$, how can I decide when to consider a new set $S'$ if the algorithm never halts when $S$ doesn't generate $G$? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have legitimately no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: You interleave the computations for each different $S$ with each other so that you go through all of them in a single infinite process, like the proof that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable.  You do the first two steps for the first $S$, then the first step for the second $S$, then the third step for the first $S$, then the second step for the second $S$, then the first step for the third $S$, then the fourth step for the first $S$, ...  (That's what it means to "dovetail" the tests.)

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!