# Questions of minimal generating sets of groups.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

There are 3 questions about minimal generating sets of groups when I am trying to prove that every subgroup of a free group is free, using Cayley graphs.

I firstly give my definition of it. For a group and a generating set $S$ of it, if any proper subset of $S$ is not a generating set, then call $S$ minimal.

Then the questions are as below:

1. Do generating sets of an arbitrary group always exist? Generating sets always exists because groups themselves are their own generating sets, but they're not minimal.
2. Is a free group freely generated by any minimal generating set?
3. For a subset $S$ of a group, can we find a minimal generating set containing $S$?

These questions seem to be obvious when I first came up with, but I didn't find a strict proof.

Comment: A minimal generating set does not always exist. You can find a counterexample here: http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/migs.pdf

Comment: @Mark Yeah I don't know what I was thinking there, I will delete my comment as it's wrong for various reasons.

Comment: Your uses of "any" are linguistically ambiguous. With my default interpretation of Question 2, the answer is obviously yes, because a free generating set of a free group is minimal.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Also, your questions are phrased as isolated problems, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the post. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry for my description. I mean for a free group $F$, for an arbitrary minimal generating set $S$ , can we show that $S$ is a freely generating set of $F$? Or in other words are there any minimal generating sets of a free group that are not freely generating sets?

Comment: @Shaun Well, the 3 are related because they're about minimal generating sets, and solving them I can prove a theorem, though they're not true as comments and answers said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some groups do not have minimal generating sets, as mentioned in the comments. For example consider $\mathbf{Q}$. In fact you can remove any element from any generating set of $\mathbf{Q}$ and the remainder must still generate.
This answers questions 1 and 3 negatively.

Question 2: $F_1 = \mathbf Z$ has a minimal generating set $\{2,3\}$, but clearly it is not freely generated by $2$ and $3$.

What *is* true is that $F_n$ is freely generated by any generating set of size $n$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447820/is-a-free-group-of-finite-rank-hopfian) or [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_free_implies_Hopfian).

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Thank you for giving me an example that is easy to be verified.

Comment: @Shaun Could you plz show me how to ask a good question?I firstly searched "minimal generating sets of groups" in this site but just find 1 question that is the same as Q1 here, which has not been solved.

Comment: Follow the link in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4650650/questions-of-minimal-generating-sets-of-groups/4650674?noredirect=1#comment9819762_4650650), @HXR.